# How do I find cheap photo studio rentals in Vancouver?

Tags: studio, renting

In the Czech Republic I am used to being able to rent a small photo studio with a set of lights, a choice of backgrounds, some tripods, etc, for about 20EUR/hour. There were also cheaper offers if you were willing to come at an unpopular time or travel outside the city center. But now that I'm staying in Vancouver, it seems that the only rentals I can find are geared towards professionals and cost 150+ CAD/hour. I only really need one small set with no assistants, so paying so much money seems excessive.

Is there a keyword I can use to find cheap photo studio rentals? Or is there nothing available for amateurs and I should just build my own photo set at home?

For reference, [here's a photo of a studio I liked in Prague](https://cdn.megapixel.cz/images/slide-show-full/6/33396.jpg). Location-wise I'm okay to rent anywhere within 20 minutes of driving from the downtown area.

*NB: I'm not asking for recommendations on particular photo studios. Instead I'm asking for advice on how to find cheap offers.*

Comment: What do you want it to look like, or what part of town do you want to be in? Vancouver is quite expensive, somewhere for half that maybe you couldn't bring clients there.

Comment: @Rob post updated.

Comment: Something like that photo will easily be more than $100 for one hour - if you go more than 20 minutes then there's SE Marine Dr. and possibly Nanaimo and Hastings area. It's not like there's a random "walk-in and rent place", you'll need to rent for months and set up your own equipment to get somewhere for (sort of) low cost. Ready-to-go won't be low cost. If you have clients they will expect to pay something, how much depends upon where you are located. Too low a cost area and they'll be looking for low cost too.

Comment: @Rob so I guess the only solution for amateurs is to just build something at home?

Comment: Buy a cube van. There's really too much competition. Here's a reasonable place but 4 hour min.: https://thisopenspace.com/spaces/3 - Here's the bad end of town, low rates but no one's going to go there: http://www.theironworks.ca/rental.html - both *look* nice inside. If you can't charge over $300 it will be charity. You'll be competing with well established places in great locations with plenty of equipment, a fancy website and a large portfolio. Best to hop in your vehicle and show up for weddings, then you pay gas only (as long as you have fancy suit and nice car).

Comment: @Rob I'm not trying to make any money - I only plan to charge people for the studio rental, not for my own work. "The Ironworks" is cheap but doesn't have any lighting equipment.

Comment: That's a good thing, people are likely to break in.

Answer (score 1):

I do not live in Vancouver so i can not answer specifically. I would try craigslist, search the artist board in community for posts. .
I did find [this post](https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/van/ats/d/large-professional-photo/6442379851.html) but no mention of cost.

Also post your own CL ad asking to network with or share space with other photographers. [Example post](https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/van/ats/d/vancouver-photography-and/6438885491.html)

You could also read the art pages of the local alternative newspaper and see if there are photography groups to join or network with. Ask local galleries if they have suggestions etc.

It is unlikely you will find something as cheap as back home but you may find something for less than what you have already found.

Perhaps you can find a photographer who will let you work for some studio time?